# Active and passive transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, symmetry, coordinate-systems

Some active transformations on the system can be seen also as passive transformations for example the rotation of the system can be seen as the rotation of the observer in the opposite direction. Anyway others transformation are just active for example the change in the number of particles in a system. So my question is, what are in general the transformation that can be seen both as passive and active?
if it's possible answer with little math, I'm now interested in understanding the concept.

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158398/