# 4-Gradient Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I am currently studying the behavior of a scalar field $\phi$ under a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$. However I am having trouble understanding why the following holds true:

$$\partial_{\mu}\left(\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)\right) = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{~~\mu}~(\partial_{\nu}\phi)\left(\Lambda^{-1}x\right).$$

This should should probably follow from the chain rule with $\Lambda$ being a linear transformation but I can't quite figure out why this is.

Comment: Your using two different notations, do you mean $\left(\partial_{\mu}\phi\right)(\Lambda^{-1}x) = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{~~\mu}~(\partial_{\nu}\phi)\left(\Lambda^{-1}x\right)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A few questions on passive vs active Lorentz transformations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135112/)

Comment: No I am meaning it as noted in the question which is also consistent to the notation in "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Peskin, Schroeder. Note that $\vec{\nabla}(f\circ g)(x)\ne (\vec{\nabla} f)(g(x))$.

Comment: Use index notation, remembering that $\partial^{\mu}x_{\nu}=\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}.$

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \phi \big( \Lambda_\nu{}^\mu x^\nu \big)  = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}  \big( \Lambda_\rho{}^\nu x^\rho \big) \left[ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y^\nu } \phi (y) \right]_{y^\mu  = \Lambda_\nu{}^\mu x^\nu}   = 
 \Lambda_\mu{}^\nu \left[ \frac{ \partial }{ \partial y^\nu } \phi (y) \right]_{y^\mu  = \Lambda_\nu{}^\mu x^\nu} ~. 
$$